# ANTLR4 mutually left-recursive error

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, antlr4, left-recursion

I currently do a recognizer in ANTLR4 and I have an error:

```
The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [expr, index_expr, member_acc, expr1]
```

This is my code:

```
num_opds: INTLIT|FLOATLIT;
bool_opds: TRUE|FALSE;
str_opds: STRINGLIT;
operators: ADD|SUB|MUL|DIV|MOD|EQUAL;
expr: <assoc=left> (<assoc=right> (ADD|SUB|NOT)? expr1) (operators (<assoc=right> (ADD|SUB|NOT)? expr1))*;
expr1: (LB expr RB)|ID|num_opds|bool_opds|str_opds|index_expr|member_acc;
index_expr: expr LSB expr RSB;
member_acc: expr DOT ID (LB expr RB)?;
```

Lexer Token:

```
LB: '(';
RB: ')';
LSB: '[';
RSB: ']';
DOT: '.';
NOT: '!';
EQUAL: '==';
```

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: And your question is...? The error is pretty clear. Refactor your grammar to eliminate the left-recursion, or merge the rules, as ANTLR4 supports direct left-recursion.

Comment: can you give me a hint? I kinda run into a dead-end in solving this problem.

Comment: *The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference*, page 73. Almost exactly your case.

Comment: I've found my answer, thank you Lucas Trzesniewski and Yuri Steinschreiber